# list of on-demand shell variables?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

**tl;dr** where can I find a list of shell variables that are on-demand (not listed by `env`)

Variables like `$OSTYPE` or `$COLUMNS` (bash) or `$RANDOM` (bash) are not listed by `env`.

Where can I find the list of these seemingly hidden environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

Using `typeset` keyword (in bash) will show all possible evaluations of `$` variables.

From `man bash`

> typeset [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
>
> Declare variables and/or give them attributes.  If no names are given then display the  values  of  variables.   The  -p  option  will  display  the attributes  and  values  of each name.

```
$ typeset
...
COLUMNS=169
...
OSTYPE=linux-gnu
...
RANDOM=23503
...
```

Also, `declare` keyword works similarly to `typeset`.

Comment: Aka. `declare`.